# What is this mystery mezzanine type connector?

Tags: identification, connector

I need to replace this connector  but I haven't been able to find anything similar.

I've tried Google Lens as well as manually trawling through a number of sites (Mouser, Digi-Key, etc.).

It's 10 pin, 2 rows, blade type, surface mount.

Any ideas?

[image: Mystery Connector]

Comment: If you can desolder it without damage, might be a marking on bottom.

Comment: Why do you want to replace it? Do you have a mating connector? Seeing that one could be helpful.

Comment: This one looks at least similar: https://www.digikey.de/de/products/detail/3m/P10-010SLT-A-G/1240005

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks very much like this P10-010SLT-A-G by 3M:

[image]<sup>Image from [North Star Micro Electronics](https://www.northstarmicro.com/connectors-interconnects/rectangular-board-to-board-connectors-arrays-edge-type-mezzanine/p10-010slt-a-g)</sup>

There's a datasheet of that one [here](https://datasheet.octopart.com/P10-010SLT-A-G-3M-datasheet-142050189.pdf), with all dimensions, so you can check if it is a useable replacement.

If it is: several sites say this part is obsolete, but [at least one supplier](https://www.northstarmicro.com/connectors-interconnects/rectangular-board-to-board-connectors-arrays-edge-type-mezzanine/p10-010slt-a-g) (no affiliation) claims to have them in stock. Maybe it is still on the 3M website as well.

Comment: That's it! Good effort finding it. It's from a current piece of medical equipment, so I'm hoping they are still being made/sold. Thanks again!